# Where can I look to see why Paperclip is failing silently in Rails 3?

Tags: paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3

I have followed the simple example [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Usage).

I have performed the generation, run the migration, added the code to my model and view, and restarted the application.

This is on a company edit screen, where the user can upload a logo.

Running Rails 3.0.3 in dev mode. The only thing even close to Paperclip that I see in the log is:

```
Started GET "/logos/original/missing.png" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 14 15:27:42 -0500 2010

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/logos/original/missing.png"):
```

I was under the impression that Paperclip was pretty easy to use, but I can't seem to even locate an error message. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes` ?

Comment: I do see this on the paperclipped model:              upload_brands GET    /brands/upload(.:format)                              {:controller=>"brands", :action=>"upload"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! The power of Google. Or Bing rather. My first problem was, I did not have my form_helper include:

```
:html => { :multipart => true }
```

That at least got the call to Paperclip going.  But it was hanging.

I am using Passenger to serve up Rails. And it turns out that Passenger did not know where ImageMagick was installed on my machine. So I added an initialization file to config/initializers called "paperclip.rb" with one line:

```
Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "/opt/local/bin"
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Please set your "default_url" path to a image which is displayed if there is no image. 
For example,

```
has_attached_file :image,
    :default_url => '/images/nopicture.jpeg',
    :styles => {
        :large => "300x300>",
        :thumb => "160x120>"
    }
```

Where "nopicture.jpeg" which is available in your "/images" folder under public is the default picture to be displayed if none is available.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Sam. And that will work fine, but my real problem is that the upload itself is not working. I +1'd you for your info but am awaiting an answer on the upload.